# Sorting an integer circular array swapping elements with 1 in between

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Given an integer circular array v, with n > 0 numbers, and only one possible move "m" is to swap one element with the one after 2 ahead.
I have to print a sequence of moves that sort v or say that's impossible (in c language)

Example:
initial: v = [8, 0, 5, 9, -1, 5]
after applying m to v[4]: v = [**-1**, 0, 5, 9, **8**, 5]
after applying m to v[3]: v = [-1, 0, 5, **5**, 8, **9**]
Which is now sorted from it's 0 position. The output would be "4 3"
What I know up to this point:
- If there are an odd number of elements, you can move any element to any position. (But is it enough to guarantee it can be sorted?)
- For an even number of elements, it's not always possible to sort it, since you can't move elements between odd and even positions (ex: v = [-1, -2, 1, 7], impossible because -2 in is an odd position, but should be at an even position).

I've been thinking about this:
- Use an auxiliar array "aux" to put the numbers with their real neighbours, like:
v = [8, 0, 5, 9, -1, 5, 6] -> aux = [8, 5, -1, 6, 0, 9, 5]
Now in aux I can perform simple swaps with adjacents numbers.
- The final configuration in terms of their position "i" in aux is:
v = [8, 0, 5, 9, -1, 5, 6] -> aux = [8, 5, -1, 6, 0, 9, 5] -> i = [0, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5]
- If n is even, there would be 2 aux, because to sort v, you can't move numbers between odd and even positions, so there's 2 sub problems. Ex:
v = [8, 0, 5, 9, -1, 5]
aux-even = [8, 5, -1] -> i-even = [0, 2, 4]
aux-odd = [0, 9, 5] -> i-even = [1, 3, 5] (thinking in terms of v)
I'm not sure where to go from here or if it's even a good path to run.
Any ideas or help are welcome.

EDIT

I'm trying to simulate the algorithm proposed by AlexD for the odd case:
v = [8, 0, 5, 9, -1, 5, 6]
v-sorted = [-1, 0, 5, 5, 6, 8, 9]

Assigning them keys (-1, **1**), (0, **5**), (5, **2**), (5, **6**), (6, **3**), (8, **7**), (9, **4**).

Back to the original order:
(8, 7) (0, 5) (5, 2) (9, 4) (-1, 1) (5, 6) (6, 3)

Using bubble sort for the keys with 1 in between.
(8, 7) (0, 5) (5, 2) (9, 4) (-1, 1) (5, 6) (6, 3)
(5, **2**) (0, 5) (8, **7**) (9, 4) (-1, 1) (5, 6) (6, 3)
(5, 2) (0, 5) (-1, **1**) (9, 4) (8, **7**) (5, 6) (6, 3)
(5, 2) (0, 5) (-1, 1) (9, 4) (6, **3**) (5, 6) (8, **7**)
(-1, **1**) (0, 5) (5, **2**) (9, 4) (6, 3) (5, 6) (8, 7)
(-1, 1) (9, **4**) (5, 2) (0, **5**) (6, 3) (5, 6) (8, 7)
(-1, 1) (9, 4) (5, 2) (0, 5) (6, 3) (5, 6) (8, 7)
But the numbers aren't sorted. What am I missing?

Comment: It is circular, so you could move it forward twice (to 2nd then to 5th position)

Comment: Thanks, @SectoKia. Actually, 4 to v[0], then v[2], then v[4].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For briefness, let me illustrate the idea by concrete cases, which are easy to generalize.

**Even case**

Let's say we have 8 elements. Then we sort two sub-array (with odd and even indices) separately, using the bubble sort with step 2, and have

```
a1    a2    a3    a4
   b1    b2    b3    b4
```

If the resulting array `a1 b1 a2 b2 a3 b3 a4 b4` happened to be sorted, we are done. Otherwise there is no solution.

**Odd case**

Let's say you have 7 elements. Sort them with your favorite method. Let's say after sorting they are

```
a5 a4 a1 a7 a3 a2 a6
```

Assign key to every element like this:

```
a5 a4 a1 a7 a3 a2 a6
 1  5  2  6  3  7  4
```

Then come back to the original order:

```
a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7
 2  7  3  5  1  4  6
```

Then sort the pairs by the new keys (`1` - `7`), using the bubble sort and with jumping over one element every time. As soon as you have the keys sorted, your `a1` ... `a7` values take their destination positions.

Let's illustrate with array

```
5 1 5 9 0
```

The sorted array and corresponding keys would be

```
0 1 5 5 9
1 4 2 5 3
```

Now let's sort pairs by key (the pairs whose keys we compare one each step are in `<>`)

```
<5 2> (1 4) <5 5> (9 3) (0 1) // starting the first loop
(5 2) (1 4) <5 5> (9 3) <0 1>
(5 2) <1 4> (0 1) (9 3) <5 5>
(5 2) <5 5> (0 1) <9 3> (1 4)
<5 2> (9 3) <0 1> (5 5) (1 4) // (5 5) is in its final position, starting the second loop
(0 1) (9 3) <5 2> (5 5) <1 4>
(0 1) <9 3> (5 2) (5 5) <1 4>
<0 1> (1 4) <5 2> (5 5) (9 3) // (1 4) in its final position, starting the third loop
(0 1) (1 4) <5 2> (5 5) <9 3>
<0 1> (1 4) <5 2> (5 5) (9 3) // (9 3) in the final position
(0 1) (1 4) (5 2) (5 5) (9 3) // (0 1) and (5 2) are in final positions
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I'm trying to understand it.

Comment: @N.Kita Just ask if you have any questions. If I'm off for today, will be back tomorrow.

Comment: I'm not sure I figured out the sorting for the odd case. :/

Comment: @N.Kita Let me try to explain. First of all, is it clear how to sort odd-length array  `7 4 5 1 2 6 3` to `1 5 2 6 3 7 4` using swaps over the middle-element?

Comment: I'm not sure. Take a look at my simulation to see if it's right?

Comment: I guess after step #4 (counting from 1): `(5, 2) (0, 5) (-1, 1) (9, 4) (6, 3) (5, 6) (8, 7)` you are supposed to swap `(0, 5)` and `(8, 7)`.

Comment: If I do so, what's the condition to stop the bubble sort, then?

Comment: You stop at element `6` (counting from `1`). Your first bubble loop compares elements at `1 3` `3 5` `5 7` `7 2` `2 4` `4 6`. The second `1 3` `3 5` `5 7` `7 2` `2 4`. The third `1 3` `3 5` `5 7` `7 2`

Comment: Can you make a simulation with this array? [5, 0, 5, 9, -1] I failed my simulation with 7 >.>

Comment: I updated the post (used `[5 1 5 9 0]` to have one character per number).

Comment: Thank you so much for you patience, AlexD. I'm implementing the even case. Tomorrow I'm gonna try to write the odd one.